# creating a new list/array in a numba function

Tags: python, numba

The function below "test_numba" gives an error:"cannot type empty list" but it works without the numba compilation.

```
def test(list_test,count):

    test_list =[]
    for all in list_test:
        test_list.append(all)

    if count ==1:

        return np.asarray(test_list, dtype=int)
    else:
        return np.asarray([1,2,3,4],dtype=int)

    test_numba = numba.jit("int64[:](int32[:],int32)")(test)
    # calling numba function
    test_numba(np.asarray([1,2,3,4],dtype=int),1)
    # calling python function
    test(np.asarray([1,2,3,4],dtype=int),1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numba signatures expect `Numpy`-Arrays. You could make it work if you just omit the signature:

```
test_numba = numba.jit()(test)
```

but since this would fallback to the Python list wouldn't provide any speedups.

With your signature you force numba to assume that an `int32` `1D numpy.array` is passed as first argument and a scalar `uint` as second. And the function should return a `int64` `1D numpy.array`. But you actually return a list, so `numba` cannot compile the function.

see also [numba signatures and eager compilation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html#eager-compilation)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I get what your saying and i tried it by having numpy arrays returned from my function but i still get the same error. After doing some testing on it, i think it's giving the error because i am trying to create a new list inside my function and numba doesn't like the empty list I create. When i remove the piece of code that does the new list creation,  it seems to be working fine. the error itself says "cannot type empty list" when i call the function.

Comment: changed the title of the question and converted lists to arrays

Comment: hey, i got it to work by creating an empty array inside of the function instead of creating an empty list. For some reason, numba doesn't like a list inside its function even when the list holds no importance. Thanks for the sugesstions. Really helped.